# What Bluetooth profiles does the Pi Zero W natively support?

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w

I've started looking for tutorials for Pi's and Bluetooth, but I don't have any experience with Bluetooth and Linux, and it seems that the Bluetooth stack on Raspbian and/or Linux is not full featured like I am used to on Windows.

What Bluetooth Profiles/capabilities does the Pi Zero W hardware and native software support?

A few examples:

- A2DP
- Serial Port
- PAN
- Low Energy
- Master/slave mode
- Connect a keyboard/mouse to the Pi Zero
- Emulate being a keyboard or mouse to another device

Full list of [Bluetooth profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles).

Ultimately, ***and anecdotally as far as this question is concerned***, I'd like to be able to SSH (or telnet) into a Pi over the Bluetooth connection, or something similar (VNC, RDP, etc.), which seems to be somewhere between not supported and not possible.

The question, answer, and comments [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53509/ssh-over-bluetooth-with-ios) make things clear as mud.  Several users report only able to connect for 1-2 seconds [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/87682/ssh-through-bluetooth-to-raspberry-pi-using-rfcomm-nothing-appears-on-bluetooth).  [This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/84820/bluetooth-pan-on-the-pi-zero-w) has no answers.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are using **Raspbian**. Together with the bluetooth stack there is also `sdptool` installed. Beside other options it has also the option `browse`. Look at `man sdptool`. With this option you can browse all available services on the device specified by a Bluetooth address as a parameter. So you can ask what services a bluetooth device nearby provides. You can also ask your local device with:

```
rpi ~$ sdptool browse local
```

This should give you a list what services available on your RasPi.